# So i have to reverse each word in the string. LIke " Hello World " ==> "olleH dlroW" but in my case it is exact opposite, it would print "dlroW olleH"

Tags: c#

```
string input = "Hello World";  
input.Reverse().ToArray();


string[] output = input.Split();  
string s1 = string.Join(" ", output);
Console.WriteLine(s1.Reverse().ToArray());
```

It would print ==>"dlroW olleH".

Comment: you have to split the words then reverse each word then create a new string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comment

```
var input = "Hello World";  
var output = string.Join(
  " ", 
  input.Split().Select(
    w => string.Concat(w.Reverse())
  )
);
```

This splits the string to words, reverses each word (resulting in a list of chars that is string.Concat'd back to being a reversed word string) and then re joins them with space separators

Spread out to multiple lines:

```
var words = input.Split();
var rwords = words.Select(w => string.Concat(w.Reverse()));
var output = string.Join(" ", rwords);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Runes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.rune?view=net-6.0) to simplify handling any string encoding problems.

```csharp
public static string ReverseEachWord(this string str)
{
    // Open a buffer the same length as the input string
    var sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length);
    // Open a FILO (First-In, Last-Out) collection to reverse each word
    var stack = new Stack<Rune>();

    foreach (var rune in str.EnumerateRunes())
    {
        if (Rune.IsWhiteSpace(rune))
        {
            // Write the reversed word to the buffer...
            while (stack.TryPop(out var stackRune))
            {
                sb.Append(stackRune);
            }

            // ... and the space
            sb.Append(rune);
        }
        else
        {
            // Put on top of the stack
            stack.Push(rune);
        }
    }

    // Dump the buffer to a new string
    return sb.ToString();
}
```